# How to parse correctly through this .txt file (it repeats every 3 lines)

Tags: c#

I need to write a WPF program containing one button, and clicking that button displays `OpenFileDialog` to select input file. From the file "sprinter.txt", sprinters are loaded into a list. Sprinter list contains fields `Name`, `Country` and list of `Times` in seconds which are times sprinter got over that year. 
The data in the file is given in the following format:

```
name_1

country_1

time_1, time_2 ... time_n

name_2

country_2

time_1, time_2 ... time_n

.....
```

And so it repeats every 3 lines. 
Every sprinter has at least one time. Check that time value is a valid real number and in case it is not just to continue processing the file.

Note: WPF part here is easy, I got that, I'll just use `button1`, `textBox1` and `textBlock1` to reference them.

Inside `button1_Click` I have this code. I've also tried splitting each line with ' ' and then when I get it and use number of words in each array to determine what it is but names and countries can have 2 words in one line so that kinda fell through.

```
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

                int counter = 0;
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null) //tried also (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string name = null;
                    string country = null;
                    if (counter == 2)
                    {
                        List<double> timeList= new List<double>();
                        String[] vr = line.Split(',');
                        for (int i = 0; i < vr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            timeList.Add(double.Parse(vr[i]));
                        }
                        sprinteri.Add(new Sprinter(name, country, timeList));
                        counter = 0;
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        name = line;
                        counter++;
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        country = line;
                        counter++;
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
              }
```

What should I try next? Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here? I'm sure it could be done in a better way then I did it but this is what I got.

I want to have all these sprinters in a list. I also have a `class Sprinter` that I use.

```
    class Sprinter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public List<double> Time = new List<double>();

        public Sprinter(string name, string country, List<double> time)
        {
            Name = time;
            Country = country;
            Time = time;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name: {0}", Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Do you get the right type of line in the right branch of your if-statement?

Comment: By the way, look into double.TryParse for the "just ignore wrong numbers" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is setting `name` and `country` to `null` inside the `while` loop. When `counter` reaches 2, note that `name` and `country` are both `null`.

To address this, move the declaration statements before the loop.

```
// Other code

string name = null; // I'd prefer string.Empty
string country = null;
while (line != null)

// Other code
```

You may also want to consider moving `line = reader.ReadLine();` outside all if-else blocks as it is repeated in all of them.